# Use $or with $elemMatch and condition outside of Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My basic structure is I have User object with a session object that contains a subjectId and an hourly price.

```
User{
    defaultHourly: Number,
    subjects{
        [
            id: String,
            hourly: Number
        ]
    }
}
```

I use elemMatch like this:

```
query.elemMatch("subjects", {
                "id": { $in: subjects },
                "$or": [
                    { "hourly": { $eq: null } }, // this is my issue
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            { "hourly": { $ne: null } },
                            { "hourly": { $gte: price.low, $lte: price.high } }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
```

the first part of elemMatch makes sure that the subjectId I want is in the array of subjects. Then I want to filter by price. if a User has null in the hourly field, I want to then compare the defaultHourly to price.low and price.high.

The issue is that defaultHourly is not a field in subjects, but is a field in the parent of subjects so I'm not sure how to access it.

I want to write:

```
"$or": [
           { 
                "$and": [
                   { "hourly": { $eq: null } },
                   { "defaultHourly": { $gte: price.low, $lte: price.high } } //this doesnt work because default hourly is not a field.
                ]
           },
           {
               "$and": [
                   { "hourly": { $ne: null } },
                   { "hourly": { $gte: price.low, $lte: price.high } }
                ]
            }
       ]
 });
```

How can I do this multilevel comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write the condition outside of the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), and put the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) at the top level of the document. This allows each "set" of conditions to apply:

```
User.find({
  "$or": [
     { 
       "defaultHourly": { "$gte": price.low, "$lte": price.high },
       "subjects": {
         "$elemMatch": { 
           "id": { "$in": subjects },
           "hourly": { "$eq": null }
         }
       }
     },
     {
       "subjects": {
         "$elemMatch": {
           "id": { "$in": subjects },
           "hourly": { "$gte": price.low, "$lte": price.high }
         }
       }
     }
  ] 
})
```

Also note the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) is not needed, since the "range" comparison would actually negate `null` since it simply would not be "greater than" an actual numeric value.

In addition, note that ALL MongoDB query expressions are already AND conditions, such as the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) on the same property. So even though it's not required, the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) can also be written in as:

```
   "hourly": { "$gte": price.low, "$lte": price.high, "$ne": null }
```

Which removes any need for an explicit [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).