# Convert query builder conditions to MongoDB operations including nested array of subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am building an application in Angular 8 on the client side and NodeJS 12 with MongoDB 4 / Mongoose 5 on the server side. I have a query generated by the [Angular2 query builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder) module. The Angular query builder object is sent to the server.

I have a server-side controller function that [converts the Angular query object to MongoDB operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099793/convert-json-query-conditions-to-mongodb-mongoose-operations). This is working perfectly for generating queries for top-level properties such as `RecordID` and `RecordType`. This is also working for building nested and/or conditions.

However, I need to also support querying an **array of subdocuments** (the "Items" array in the example schema).

**Schema**

Here is the example schema I am trying to query:

```
{
  RecordID: 123,
  RecordType: "Item",
  Items: [
    {
      Title: "Example Title 1",
      Description: "A description 1"
    },
    {
      Title: "Example 2",
      Description: "A description 2"
    },
    {
      Title: "A title 3",
      Description: "A description 3"
    },
  ]
}
```

**Working example**

*Top-level properties only*

Here's an example of the query builder output with and/or conditions on top-level properties only:

```
{ "condition": "or", "rules": [ { "field": "RecordID", "operator": "=", "value": 1 }, { "condition": "and", "rules": [ { "field": "RecordType", "operator": "=", "value": "Item" } ] } ] }
```

Here's the query builder output after it has been converted to MongoDB operations on top-level properties only:

```
{ '$expr': { '$or': [ { '$eq': [ '$RecordID', 1 ] }, { '$and': [ { '$eq': [ '$RecordType', 'Item' ] } ] } ] }}
```

that converts the angular query object to mongodb operators.

Here is the existing query conversion function that

```
const conditions = { "and": "$and", "or": "$or" };
const operators = { "=": "$eq", "!=": "$ne", "<": "$lt", "<=": "$lte", ">": "$gt", ">=": "$gte" };

const mapRule = rule => ({
    [operators[rule.operator]]: [ "$"+rule.field, rule.value ]
});

const mapRuleSet = ruleSet => {
    return {
        [conditions[ruleSet.condition]]: ruleSet.rules.map(
            rule => rule.operator ? mapRule(rule) : mapRuleSet(rule)
        )
    }
};

let mongoDbQuery = { $expr: mapRuleSet(q) };
console.log(mongoDbQuery);
```

**Issue**

The function works for top-level properties only such as RecordID and RecordType, but I need to **extend it to support the Items array of subdocuments**.

Apparently, to query properties in nested arrays of subdocuments, the `$elemMatch` operator must be used, based on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258776/mongodb-expression-to-query-array-of-subdocuments). However, in my case, the $expr is necessary to build the nested and/or conditions so I can't simply switch to `$elemMatch`.

**QUESTION**

How can I extend the query conversion function to also support $elemMatch to query arrays of subdocuments? Is there a way to get the $expr to work?

**UI query builder**

Here is the UI query builder with the nested "Items" array of subdocuments. In this example, the results should match RecordType equals "Item" AND Items.Title equals "Example Title 1" OR Items.Title contains "Example".

[image: Angular query builder with nested array of objects]

Here is the output generated by the UI query builder. Note: The `field` and `operator` property values are configurable.

```
{"condition":"and","rules":[{"field":"RecordType","operator":"=","value":"Item"},{"condition":"or","rules":[{"field":"Items.Title","operator":"=","value":"Example Title 1"},{"field":"Items.Title","operator":"contains","value":"Example"}]}]}
```

UPDATE: I may have found a query format that works with the nested and/or conditions with the `$elemMatch` as well. I had to remove the `$expr` operator since `$elemMatch` does not work inside of expressions. I took inspiration from the [answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786973/use-or-with-elemmatch-and-condition-outside-of-array).

This is the query that is working. The next step will be for me to figure out how to adjust the query builder conversion function to create the query.

```
{
  "$and": [{
      "RecordType": {
        "$eq": "Item"
      }
    },
    {
      "$or": [{
          "RecordID": {
            "$eq": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "Items": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "Title": { "$eq": "Example Title 1" }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: in MongoDB you have two ways to query such array: 1) $elemMatch can be used to find at least one element matching all conditions 2) dot notation like "Items.Title" will try to find any `Example Title 1` and all the other criteria will be applied separately so the don't have to apply to the same array element. Is there any way to determine which way of filtering you're trying to apply ?

Comment: I think it would be #2 since I want to find all Records that match the and/or conditions in the builder respectively. The issue is that the dot notation isn't working in the $expr the way it is set up now (although it works perfectly for top-level properties). Hopefully that answers the question. Thanks again.

Comment: can you define other property inside `const conditions = { "and": "$and", "or": "$or" };` 
Like adding `elemMatch`
Ex: conditions = { "and": "$and", "or": "$or", "elemMatch": "$elemMatch" };`

Comment: @ShivamMishra Thanks for the suggestion! I am thinking something along those lines. The complication is that the subdocument query still needs to be wrapped in the "and/or" conditions to implement the query generated by the condition builder. So far I haven't been able to get $elemMatch working within the context of the $expr operator.

Comment: @mickl Re-evaluating your last question, I think #1 will work actually. The purpose of the query builder is to return a list of Records, so I just need to know which Records match the conditions. So in this case, if at least one "Items" element matches the $elemMatch conditions then the Record should be returned as a result.

Comment: @pengz I see what you mean. Unfortuantely there's no good solution here since both condtions for `Item` appear as separate `rules` so previous solution works as expected here. Please keep in mind that you can also store a document like this in your database: `{ Items: { Title: "Example Title 1" } }` so the library itself should have a way to distinguish between arrays and nested docs.

Comment: @mickl Sorry to keep bombarding you just wanted to clarify my last comment. Re: "so the library itself should have a way to distinguish between arrays and nested docs" I can add another property to the config object to identify whether the field is an array or nested object. Or, I could add a hard-coded condition in the to check if the field name contains "Items" and just picking off the field name after the dot. It doesn't need to be super elegant or reusable and some parts can be hard-coded for this particular schema. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @pengz so in previous solution you can ignore all fields where path is specified with dot notation like `Items.Title` and then you need to loop through your structure and accumulate them into single `$elemMatch`

Comment: Just for clarification: why is your final query syntax is something like `{ '$eq': [ '$RecordID', 1 ] }` rather than `{ 'RecordID': { '$eq': 1} }` or `{ 'RecordID': 1 }`?

Comment: @ymz Since it generates nested and/or conditions inside of an expression. There can be potentially many other fields and operators, such as `{"$expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":["$RecordType","Item"]},{"$or":[{"$eq":["$RecordID",1]},{"$ne":["$RecordID",2]},{"$gt":["$RecordID",1000]}]}]}}`

Comment: @ymz Oh I see what you mean, I suppose the brackets here are not required: `{"$eq":["$RecordType","Item"]}`

Comment: great! one more thing: it is still valid to user this kind of query in your project `{ '$eq': [ '$Items.Title', 'Example' ] }`?

Comment: @ymz Thanks! I believe that works by itself but not inside the $expr operator. I need $elemMatch to get it to work inside the $expr operator. I had a separate question about that previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258776/mongodb-expression-to-query-array-of-subdocuments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more research I have a working solution. Thanks to all of the helpful responders who provided insight.

The function takes a query from the Angular query builder module and converts it to a MongoDB query.

Angular query builder

```
  {
    "condition": "and",
    "rules": [{
      "field": "RecordType",
      "operator": "=",
      "value": "Item"
    }, {
      "condition": "or",
      "rules": [{
        "field": "Items.Title",
        "operator": "contains",
        "value": "book"
      }, {
        "field": "Project",
        "operator": "in",
        "value": ["5d0699380a2958e44503acfb", "5d0699380a2958e44503ad2a", "5d0699380a2958e44503ad18"]
      }]
    }]
  }
```

MongoDB query result

```
  {
    "$and": [{
      "RecordType": {
        "$eq": "Item"
      }
    }, {
      "$or": [{
        "Items.Title": {
          "$regex": "book",
          "$options": "i"
        }
      }, {
        "Project": {
          "$in": ["5d0699380a2958e44503acfb", "5d0699380a2958e44503ad2a", "5d0699380a2958e44503ad18"]
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
```

Code

```
/**
 * Convert a query object generated by UI to MongoDB query
 * @param query a query builder object generated by Angular2QueryBuilder module
 * @param model the model for the schema to query
 * return a MongoDB query
 * 
 */

apiCtrl.convertQuery = async (query, model) => {

  if (!query || !model) {
    return {};
  }

  const conditions = { "and": "$and", "or": "$or" };
  const operators = {
    "=": "$eq",
    "!=": "$ne",
    "<": "$lt",
    "<=": "$lte",
    ">": "$gt",
    ">=": "gte",
    "in": "$in",
    "not in": "$nin",
    "contains": "$regex"
  };

  // Get Mongoose schema type instance of a field
  const getSchemaType = (field) => {
    return model.schema.paths[field] ? model.schema.paths[field].instance : false;
  }

  // Map each rule to a MongoDB query
  const mapRule = (rule) => {

    let field = rule.field;
    let value = rule.value;

    if (!value) {
      value = null;
    }

    // Get schema type of current field
    const schemaType = getSchemaType(rule.field);

    // Check if schema type of current field is ObjectId
    if (schemaType === 'ObjectID' && value) {
      // Convert string value to MongoDB ObjectId
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.map(val => new ObjectId(val));
      } else {
        value = new ObjectId(value);
      }
    // Check if schema type of current field is Date
    } else if (schemaType === 'Date' && value) {
      // Convert string value to ISO date
      console.log(value);
      value = new Date(value);
    }

    console.log(schemaType);
    console.log(value);

    // Set operator
    const operator = operators[rule.operator] ? operators[rule.operator] : '$eq';

    // Create a MongoDB query
    let mongoDBQuery;

    // Check if operator is $regex
    if (operator === '$regex') {
      // Set case insensitive option
      mongoDBQuery = {
        [field]: {
          [operator]: value,
          '$options': 'i'
        }
      };
    } else {
      mongoDBQuery = { [field]: { [operator]: value } };
    }

    return mongoDBQuery;

  }

  const mapRuleSet = (ruleSet) => {

    if (ruleSet.rules.length < 1) {
      return;
    }

    // Iterate Rule Set conditions recursively to build database query
    return {
      [conditions[ruleSet.condition]]: ruleSet.rules.map(
        rule => rule.operator ? mapRule(rule) : mapRuleSet(rule)
      )
    }
  };

  let mongoDbQuery = mapRuleSet(query);

  return mongoDbQuery;

}
```